# Python Regex: Parse key/value pairs from a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to disect a string like the following into a list of key/value pairs:

```
line1 = "keyword1: value1 keyword2: value2 keyword1: value3 keyword3: value4"
```

I wrote the following code using regex to achieve that goal:

```
import re

line1 = "keyword1: value1 keyword2: value2 keyword1: value3 keyword3: value4"

keywords = [ re.escape(k) for k in ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3'] ]

any_keyword = '|'.join(keywords)
regex = "(" + any_keyword + "):(.+?)(?:" + any_keyword + "|$)"

print(line1)
print(regex)

for m in re.finditer(regex, line1):
  print(m)
```

The matches I get are

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 25), match='keyword1: value1 keyword2'>
<re.Match object; span=(34, 59), match='keyword1: value3 keyword3'>
```

and, of course, they include keyword2 and keyword3 at the end of the string so that I don't get additional Match objects for those keywords.

How can I receive 4 matches, one for each keyword in the line?

Comment: Use a *lookahead* - `regex = "(" + any_keyword + "):(.+?)(?=(?:" + any_keyword + "):|$)"`. Add `:` in the lookahead after keyword to make it safer. See https://ideone.com/88o81D

Comment: are there any chance to have space in key and value?  Imho, a way like the answer from @TJCWood does make sense, by simply looking up non-space pair around a colon

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you don't need an extra non-capturing group in the lookahead group.  Simply `(?=key1|key2|key3|$)` will work

Comment: @AdrianShum It is necessary because of `:`. Every keyword is followed with `:`, we do not want to stop matching before a `:` in the value part.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah ha! It makes sense. I missed your extra colon  :)

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the matches using a lookahead rather than a non-capturing group as the last pattern in the regex since a non-capturing group pattern still consumes characters:

```
import re
line1 = "keyword1: value1 keyword2: value2 keyword1: value3 keyword3: value4"
keywords = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3']
any_keyword = '|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))
regex = "(" + any_keyword + "):(.+?)(?=(?:" + any_keyword + "):|$)"
print([m.group() for m in re.finditer(regex, line1)])
# => ['keyword1: value1 ', 'keyword2: value2 ', 'keyword1: value3 ', 'keyword3: value4']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/88o81D)

If your keys can contain whitespace, make sure to sort the keys before defining `any_keyword` pattern by sorting them by length in descending order, e.g. `sorted(keywords,key=len,reverse=True)`.

It might be a good idea to match keywords as whole words, too:

```
regex = r"\b(" + any_keyword + r"):(.+?)(?=\b(?:" + any_keyword + "):|$)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/73He2W/2). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)` - Group 1: keyword alternatives
- `:` - a `:` char
- `(.+?)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\b(?:keyword1|keyword2|keyword3):|$)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure that, immediately to the right of the current position, there is either

  - `\b(?:keyword1|keyword2|keyword3):` - any keyword from the list followed with `:`
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `re.split`:

```
line1 = "keyword1: value1 keyword2: value2 keyword1: value3 keyword3: value4"
l = re.split('(keyword\d+):', line1)[1:]

[(k,v.strip()) for k, v in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
```

Output:

```
[('keyword1', 'value1'),
 ('keyword2', 'value2'),
 ('keyword1', 'value3'),
 ('keyword3', 'value4')]
```

Answer (score -1):

another way

```
>>> regex = "(" + any_keyword + "):\s(\w+)"
>>> pattern = re.compile(regex)
>>> pattern.search(line1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 16), match='keyword1: value1'>
>>> pattern.findall(line1)
[('keyword1', 'value1'), ('keyword2', 'value2'), ('keyword1', 'value3'), ('keyword3', 'value4')]
>>>
```

Comment: It will only support one "word-char" word values.